# How to track product creation / manufacturing status?

Tags: orders, order-status

I am running Magento Community Edition 1.9.x. This is a new build with no extensions installed and no customer development... yet.

We print products on demand. A customer orders a poster off of our website and we print it to order. We also frame and produce other gift products in house. Is there a way to track a products production status in Magento? This status must be at the product level, not the order level. The most basic need is the ability to see each item in the order to a custom (tag, label, etc), whatever you want to call it.

Customer orders a photo poster. I want the option to change a custom value for that product to options like: Not Printed, Not Framed, Matted, Framed, Completed, etc. That's all it needs to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without coding the best approach is to use the "Add comment to order" built in feature and simply add a pertinent comment like "Product A has status A1" and then "Product A has status B1" and so on.

Once the order is placed you can access it under Sales - Orders and on the lower left corner you will se an input where you can add comments to the order and send them (or not) to the customer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately order level notes is not a feasible solution for us. Often orders have up to 30 items in them, each one with status that change daily. Tracking all of the statuses in the notes will get overwhelming quickly. I also want to keep the order statuses consistent among my employees. Having preset status options for each item would work best.